# Doubts about Messages being overwritten?

Tags: c, message

Assuming a message comes from an outside source generator at at interval of 1 second.I have two handler functions which gets called whenever these message comes based on the fields of the message

**I am having a function which creates a thread routine named WriteSM.**

consider a message of 2 bytes having 2 fields
  1)data
  2Type

We have two handler functions for each of the fields which are shown below

```
void HandlerforData(char data)

void handlerforType(char Type)

            /*This is the sample piece of code*/
            char buffer[4];/*Global buffer*/
            int index = 0;
            static int flag = 0;/*A global static flag*/
            void HandlerforData(char data);
            void WriteSM(void);
            void handlerforType(char Type);


            /*Two handler functions*/
            void HandlerforData(char data)
            {

                   buffer[index] = data;
            }
            void handlerforType(char Type)
            {

              buffer[index+1] = type;
                   buffer[index+3] = '\0';/*Null terminated the string*/
              index = 0;
                   flag = 1
       }


          void WriteSM(void)
          {

                    while(1)
                    {
                         if(flag ==1)
                         {
                             /*Opens a shared memory and writes to the shared memory*/
                             flag =0/*Reset the flag*/
                         }
                    }                      

           }
```

Assuming my message comes in an interval of 1 second,how will i ensure that the buffer doesnt gets overwritten with the next frame of message?

Please do get back to me if you have any concerns

Thanks and regards
Maddy

Comment: I think you need to tell us about how the (presumed) multi-threading is implemented - specifically problems arise if this chunk of code can be called from different threads using the same 'global' buffer.

Comment: modified the code with more information

Comment: Are you trying to write data into buffer(Which should be declared as char buffer[2] at the very least)? Is this data binary e.g. is '0' or null a valid value?

Comment: @ChrisBD..Sorry for the confusion.Its a char buffer[4].

Answer (score 0):

I guess its a multi threaded app, you should definitely provide more informations next time, however try to google mutual exclusions in relation to critical sections.

Comment: @Starfighter911..What more information you expect?I shall try my best to provide the same